# Entering title on a photo or a series of photos on IOS

Tags: iphone, camera

Until Google or Adobe come up with something, finding personal photos is currently like finding a needle in a haystack.

To overcome this issue, I'm thinking of starting a new regime of writing a title/short description on all / a series of photo that I just took on the iPhone. The ideal use case would be:

1. **upon taking a photo** (not a separate workflow), I will be able to enter a short snippet before posting photos on instagram
2. instead of posting the title on a social network, I'd like it to be written to the EXIF of the photo file so that it's still intact wherever it goes (iPhoto, Lightroom, etc.).

Is there a photo app that allows me to do this? or do I need to use a separate EXIF editor to do this (which will be annoying really)

Ron

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the 500px app.

Here is [information](https://support.500px.com/customer/portal/articles/364419-%E2%80%A8how-do-i-add-or-edit-exif-information-) from them how to modify the EXIF in photos.

> If your photo has EXIF data included in the file, it should be
>   automatically added when you upload it. If this does not work for you,
>   please email help@500px.com and include the photo that you're having
>   troubles with.
>
> If your photo does not include EXIF data or you wish to manually edit
>   it, follow these directions:
>
> 1. Login to 500px.com
> 2. Go to your Organizer.
> 3. Hover over the thumbnail of the photo you’d like to adjust and press Edit.
> 4. On the right hand side of the edit screen, there are fields for the Meta/EXIF data. These fields are automatically filled if the
>      information is available.
> 5. Edit this data, and then press Save at the bottom of the page.
>
> Step by step visual guide: